# Compare two large txt file and return differences using PowerShell or C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have to compare two large files and return the difference of 2 files

```
$result= Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content D:\Scalability\misc\1.txt) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content D:\Scalability\misc\1.txt) | Select -Property InputObject
$result.InputObject
```

above code working for the small file only and file size are 1GB

Comment: And what is your questiopn? What did you try? There are so many similar questions around, even complete tools that do it for you.

Comment: For clarity, please add in details like what you are trying to achieve, what problem you are running into, the output you are getting and the expected output. Also include what you have already tried and what you have already read / researched so we don't duplicate efforts here.

Comment: Hi I want to compare 2 big files and i want difference given 2 file using powershell script or C#

Answer (score 1):

Use FC command like below:

```
FC /a C:\demo\input.txt H:\work\output.txt
```

`/a` is for ASCII compare

p.s FC stands for file compare

p.s More in the docs: https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html

p.s in powershell we have to write fc.exe or even full path `C:\windows\system32\fc.exe` because FC is an alias in PowerShell

Comment: FC /a D:\Scalability\misc\1.txt D:\Scalability\misc\2.txt
Format-Custom : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'D:\Scalability\misc\1.txt'.
At line:1 char:1
+ FC /a D:\Scalability\misc\1.txt D:\Scalability\misc\2.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Format-Custom], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatCustomCommand

Comment: write fc.exe instead

Comment: @MaheshGaikwad I updated answer it is because Powershell has an Alias FC for the Format-Custom cmdlet, therefore to run the 'old' FC under PowerShell you need to run fc.exe or full path to fc.exe

Comment: Thanks, But i want only different lines from 2 txt file. below is result if i use above code   C:\windows\system32\fc.exe /a D:\Scalability\misc\1.txt D:\Scalability\misc\2.txt
Comparing files D:\SCALABILITY\MISC\1.txt and D:\SCALABILITY\MISC\2.TXT
***** D:\SCALABILITY\MISC\1.txt
6
8
10
***** D:\SCALABILITY\MISC\2.TXT
6
...
10
*****

Comment: File 1 have lines 1
2
3
4
5
6
8
10
11
12 and File 2 have 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12 i want result 7 and 9 line which are not exits in file 1

Comment: Edit your question and share the sample output you are getting and what you are expecting from us